# pyopencv drawContours

Tags: opencv

I use pyopencv to find contours but I cannot draw the found contours. I got the error:

> ```
>  23 color = Scalar(255)
>  24 print type(color)
> ```
>
> ---> 25 drawContours(img, list(contours), -1, color)
>        26
>        27 imshow('Xe may - 0', img)
>
> ArgumentError: Python argument types
>   in
>       pyopencv.pyopencvext.drawContours(Mat,
>   list, int, Scalar) did not match C++
>   signature:
>       drawContours(cv::Mat {lvalue} image,
>   std::vector,
>   std::allocator > >,
>   std::allocator,
>   std::allocator > > > >
>   contours, int contourIdx,
>   cv::Scalar_ color, int
>   thickness=1, int lineType=8,
>   std::vector,
>   std::allocator > >
>   hierarchy=vector_Vec4i(len=0, []), int
>   maxLevel=2147483647, cv::Point_
>   offset=Point2i(x=0, y=0)) WARNING:
>   Failure executing file:

Here is my code

```
# load image
img = imread('37S2231.jpg')
# gray scale
out = img.clone()
cvtColor(img, out, CV_RGB2GRAY)
# equalizes the histogram of a grayscale image
# increases the contrast of the image
out2 = out.clone()
equalizeHist(out, out2)
# canny to extract edges
out3 = out2.clone()
Canny(out2, out3, 150, 200)
# threshold
out4 = out3.clone()
threshold(out3, out4, 254, 255, THRESH_BINARY)
# contours
contours = findContours(out4, 1, 1)
print type(contours)
color = Scalar(255)
print type(color)
drawContours(img, list(contours), -1, color)
```

I have checked the drawContours function at  http://packages.python.org/pyopencv/2.1.0.wr1.0.2/ but it looks similar to my code. Did I do something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

first of all thanks for this example, it's the only one I found to illustrate the usage of pyopencv.findContours. To your problem: use contours[0] instead of list(contours)! So, change the last line to

```
drawContours(img, contours[0], -1, color)
```

Comment: with OpenCV 3.x and 4.0 in that case contours is a tuple because findContours return three arguments:

findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]]) -> image, contours, hierarchy

Because the contours are not the first returned arg but the second it is: drawContours(img, contours[1], -1, color)